# nodejs & fast-csv : how do i modify an existing csv file without overriding it?

Tags: node.js, csv

```
id        | minQty
--------------------
p1        | 10
--------------------
p2        | 20
--------------------
p3        | 30
--------------------
p4        | 40
--------------------
p5        | 50
--------------------
```

above is a sample of how my csv file is structured. i've been searching around and i only see how to read and write files. **I cant find anything on modifying existing csv file.**

here im trying to:

> > 1) delete a record
> >
> > 2) modify a record minQty
> >
> > 3) append a new record

i'm pretty new to nodejs and fast-csv. thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: If the file is a reasonable size you can read entire file then change what you need and write it back to the same file. But if it's a large file the best you can do is to read your csv file line-by-line, modify and write it again line-by-line to a new file. Then delete the old file and rename the new file. You cannot write to a file you are reading.

Comment: @Molda Hi Molda. Thanks for the reply. Am i right to say then there are no direct apis to delete, modify and append a new record? I'll have to either create a new file or override the existing file? Thanks!

Comment: Yes that's right. You have to think about how the file is written on the disc. Imagine you changed first record `p1 | 10` to `p1 | 1000` then the entire file starting at second line would have to be moved by couple of bytes because there would be no space for those two extra zeros. That's why there are databases that are optimized for this kind of operation and can change a record without having to move entire file everytime you change something.

Comment: @Molda Hi Molda. Thanks!